# How do I use the shared stash to transfer items between my characters?

Tags: borderlands-2

Pre-release information on Borderlands 2 declared there would be a "shared stash" which you can use to transfer between your created characters. How do I access the shared stash?

Comment: You can also still use the old BL1 trick of having a friend creating a game (preferably invite only), dropping the weapon, exiting and switching to the new character, rejoining while the friend keeps the same game instance up, and picking the weapon back up. Of course, this relies on trust in your friend.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The stash box is located in the northwest corner of Sanctuary, just past Zed's clinic. To get access to the stash, talk to Claptrap (who is in the same location) and he will give you an absurdly "impossible" mission. Follow the mission to its conclusion, which will point out the position of the stash. You can deposit up to 4 items in the shared stash, which you can remove with any other characters you create.

See also [this walkthrough video on IGN](http://www.ign.com/videos/2012/09/17/borderlands-2-walkthrough-claptraps-secret-stash-side-missions-part-7).

Comment: It's worth noting that you can increase the stash size via upgrades as well.

Comment: FYI, you don't get access to the mission from Claptrap _immediately_ upon arriving at Sanctuary, but after the first story mission in the zone. It's pretty quick to do though, so not a big deal.

Comment: I was wrong about the stash size, too.  It's the personal storage you increase via upgrades, not the account-wide stash (bummer).

Comment: @peacedog - You can create a 'Bank' character whose job is only to stand outside the secret stash and take items. Due to the feature (glitch?) of being able to withdraw past your backpack limit, you can effectively have unlimited storage space using this method

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the stash box mentioned in the [current accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84725/4797), in [True](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/True_Vault_Hunter_Mode) / [Ultimate](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Mode) Vault Hunter Mode, you can also access [Claptrap's Secret Stash](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Claptrap%27s_Secret_Stash) near the starting location of the game.

It is found at [Claptrap's Place, Windshear Waste](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Windshear_Waste#Claptrap.27s_Place) (in a closet where several broken claptraps are stored and the first "Cult of the Vault" symbol can be found).